# Cannot use the PhoneGap barcode scanner plugin in Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I followed the [tutorial here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3) to install the phonegap plugin in my Android project.

The version of Cordova (PhoneGap) is 2.3.0, and I download the plugin from [this github link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins);

Here is my code where I try to call the barcode scanner:

```
  window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(success,
     function(error) {
        alert("scanning failed: " + error)
     }
  );
```

When I press the button to call the method, I get the following error:

```
scanning failed : Class not found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add the line:

```
<plugin name="BarcodeScanner" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner"/>
```

to you res/xml/config.xml file.

Comment: I am sure I did that already. 
I also add the following permission to the AndroidManifest.xml: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

Answer (score -1):

Add the line to you res/xml/config.xml file:

```
<feature name="BarcodeScanner"><param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" /></feature>
```